# Query for not getting Child element using Linq-XML?

Tags: linq-to-xml

I have xml file like this.

```
<School Include="Y">
 <Element ID="1" Name="ONE"/>
 <Element ID="2" Name="TWO"/>
 <Element ID="3" Name="THREE"/>
  <Child1 Include="N">
     <Element ID="4" Name="FOUR"/>
  </Child1>
<Element ID="5" Name="FIVE"/>

</School>
```

I have to write query to get as:

```
<Element ID="1" Name="ONE"/>
 <Element ID="2" Name="TWO"/>
 <Element ID="3" Name="THREE"/>
<Element ID="5" Name="FIVE"/>
```

How to write Linq to XML query for getting above output?

Answer (score 1):

```
var nodes = xdoc.Root.Elements("Element");
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming "Test.xml" is your file.

```
var document = XElement.Load("Test.xml");//Specify your file path
var elements = document.Decendants("Element");

foreach(var element in elements)
{

}
```

Thanks
Ashwani